# Solve for an unknown value in R

Tags: r, function, optimization

I have an equation `ln(1 - P) * ln(1 - X2/d) = ln(1 - Q) * ln(1 - X1/d)`. I want to determine the `d`vlaue. I wrote the following `r` code.

```
Q = 0.75
P = 0.5
X2 = 5.57665
X1 = 1.473618
fun = function(d) (log(1-P)*log(1 - X2/d) - log(1 - Q)*log(1 - X1/d))^2
optimize(fun, c(0, 1000), maximum = TRUE, tol = 1e-10)
```

Does the above code correct? I set the interval `c(0, 1000)`. How to select the appropriate one? Also, is there any other way to find `d`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for starters, check if there is even a solution to this equation, which is luckily in this x-range:

```
library(ggplot2)

f1 <- function(d) log(1-P)*log(1-X2/d)
f2 <- function(d) log(1-Q)*log(1-X1/d)

(p <- ggplot() +
  xlim(-12, 12) + 
  ylim(-10, 10) +
  geom_function(fun = f1, n = 1E4, aes(color = "f1")) +
  geom_function(fun = f2, n = 1E4, aes(color = "f2")))
```

[image]

Note that there is a vertical asymptote at x = 0 and a horizontal asymptote at y = 0. This will be helpful setting the search interval.

Next, you need to have your equation correct. I'm not sure where the `^2` came from. Moving the LHS of the equation to the RHS you get this function:

```
f <- function(d) log(1-P)*log(1-X2/d) - (log(1-Q)*log(1-X1/d))
```

That we can solve with the `uniroot` function from base `R`:

```
(eq <- uniroot(f, lower = -10, upper = -0.01))
$root
[1] -0.8258847

$f.root
[1] -5.59396e-06

$iter
[1] 10

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

And to confirm with the plot:

```
p + 
  geom_point(data = data.frame(x = eq$root, y = f1(eq$root)), aes(x = x, y = y))
```

Note `y` could have been found with either `f1` or `f2` since they're equal at this point. Also this value was found through optimization so there is some error as shown by `eq$estim.prec`.

[image]

Comment: thanks. Why can't we use the `optimize` function here? Also, can I use `nlm`?

Comment: You want to find where this function equals zero, eg these two lines cross. Take a look at the graph of `f` and think about what `optimize` or `nlm` would return. They'll find the minimum or maximum over a given interval. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: oh ok. I got it.